# How can I solve the problem with Sumo in line launchconfig in omnet.ini?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, omnet++, veins, sumo

I am working on windows 10 64 bit/Edition : Windows 10 Pro, version: 22H2 (2004),Experience: Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.19041.1000.0 ,OS build :19045.3086 . I unpacked OMNeT++ 5.0 and in `configure.user` I have set:

```
 prefer-clang=no
```

or

```
prefer -clang =yes
```

and execute `./configure` and then `make`, the output gcc-release, gcc-debug.
My microsoft visual studio version is MS 2008. Do I must install VS in higher version for example 2010 or high or change OMNeT++ version? My simulation files don't give errors when I am executing build for my project, but when I arrive to my simulation sumo interface and choose one section from my simulation, it gives the following message that belongs xml files
:

> <!> Error in module (Veins::TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd) VANET.manager (id=6) during network setup: While evaluating parameter `launchConfig': Error reading` F:/omnetpp-5.0/UV-CAST-protocol/simulations/_maps/downtownorlando/downtownorlando50_1.launchd.xml': Parse error: failed to load external entity "F:/omnetpp-5.0/UV-CAST-protocol/simulations/_maps/downtownorlando/downtownorlando50_1.launchd.xml"
> at line (null):0

My veins is veins 4.4, my sumo is sumo 0.25.
This line in omnet.ini file is

```
*.manager.launchConfig = xmldoc("F:/omnetpp-5.0/UV-CAST-protocol/simulations/_maps/downtownorlando/downtownorlando"+ string(${Traffic=50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300})+ "_" + string(${repetition}) + ".launchd.xml")
```

Note.
I unpacked OMNeT++ 5.6.2 and modify  `configure.user`:

```
prefer-clang=no
```

and execute `./configure` and then `make` ...the output gcc-release, gcc-debug, but

```
prefer-clang=yes
```

...the output clang-release,clang-debug

My microsoft visual studio version is 2008. I can't execute the simulation in OMNeT++ 5.6.2 and veins 5.2 because I work in veins 4.4.

[image]

Comment: I installed  codeBlocks that contains within path :"C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin" all applications that belong gcc,g++,x86_64-w64-mingw32-c++,mingw32-make,x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc,x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++...........What are the code fragments to be inserted when I execute make make of src from my simulation properties when using omnet 5.0 version or previous version ? from omnet 5.0 properities :models are  compiled as C++11 sources .this means that codeblocks is helpless with omnet5.0 because supports clang not gcc .must be installed visual studio code or visual studio c++ 2010 or high .

Comment: I know following code fragments are added when makemake of src :## Use the new message compiler introduced in OMNeT++ 5.3 # MSGC:=$(MSGC) --msg6 ifeq ($(PLATFORM),win32.x86_64) # # on windows we have to link with the ws2_32 (winsock2) library as it is no longer added # to the omnetpp system libraries by default (as of OMNeT++ 5.1) # LIBS += -lws2_32 DEFINES += -DINET_EXPORT ENABLE_AUTO_IMPORT=-Wl,--enable-auto-import LDFLAGS := $(filter-out $(ENABLE_AUTO_IMPORT), $(LDFLAGS)) endif but tested it with omnet 5.6.2 /work correctly because supports prefer gcc over clang or opposite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you are using OMNeT++ for Windows, you do not need Microsoft Visual Studio at all. The package for Windows contains already all necessary tools including compilators.
2. Make sure that all files pointed in the parameter `launchConfig` exist.
3. Could you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71460684/edit) your question and present one of the files from the above mentioned parameter, for example `F:/omnetpp-5.0/UV-CAST-protocol/simulations/_maps/downtownorlando/downtownorlando50_0.launchd.xml`?